# MySQL query to display name from sender and receiver

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called  `users`  which looks like this:

```
 +----+----------------+
 | id | name           | 
 +----+----------------+
 |  1 | Blake          | 
 |  2 | Jenn           | 
 +----+----------------+
```

And i have a table called  `msg`  which looks like this:

```
 +----+----------------+----------------+
 | id | sender         | receiver       | 
 +----+----------------+----------------+
 |  1 | 1              | 2              |
 |  2 | 2              | 1              |
 +----+----------------+----------------+
```

So now i have a problem because i can't figure out how to join msg.sender(id) to users.name(name).

So basicly what i want to end up with, looks kind of like this:

```
 +----+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 | id | sender         | sender_name    | receiver       | receiver_name  |
 +----+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 |  1 | 1              | Blake          | 2              | Jenn           |
 |  2 | 2              | Jenn           | 1              | Blake          |
 +----+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I hope these illustrations kind of help with what I'm trying to explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `join` the `users` table twice with `msg` table - Once on sender and  then on receiver.

```
select m.*,
    s.name as sender_name,
    r.name as receiver_name
from msg m
join users s on m.sender = s.id
join users r on m.receiver = r.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should join the user table twice using alias

```
  select  msg.sender, u1.name  as sender_name, msg.receiver, u2.name as receiver_name
  from msg
  inner join users u1 on u1.id =  msg.sender
  inner join users u2 on u2.id =  msg.receiver
```